# cloudera manager downgrade process

Tags: cloudera, downgrade

I upgraded CM 5.8.3, CDH 5.7.5 to CM 5.11.0, CDH 5.9.1 in our cluster
Then I applied the Sentry and spark 2.0 version.
So HDFS data not added but HDFS permmision and owner changed

Anyway, I had to install CM version 5.10.1, but I found myself installing a version of CM version 5.11.0.

Though there is no problem with the our cluster,
my manager wants to reinstall the CM 5.10.1 in our cluster
because it has different another cluster

So I have a question about downgrade.

I'd like to know if CM downgrade is possible with below command :

yum downgrade cloudera-manager-agent , cloudera-manager-daemons, cloudera-manager-server

If it is impossible, please confirm if the following process is correct.

I hope to downgrade only CM 5.11.1 to CM 5.11.0

1. yum remove CM 5.11.0
2. yum install CM 5.8.5(because metadata backup vesion is 5.8.3)
3. Restore the following Cloudera Manager databases:
   Cloudera Manager Server
   Activity Monitor (depending on your deployment, this role may not be installed)
   Reports Manager
   Service Monitor
   Host Monitor
   Navigator Audit Server
   Navigator Metadata Server

I am worried that CM will not start because the cdh version stored in the scm metastore 
does not match the actual installed version of CDH.
so below process(5~6 and 8) likely to be needed.

## is it right ?

5. restore HDFS Metastore(fsimage, editslog) in active namenode
6. CDH 5.9.1 deactivate and CDH 5.7.5 activate
7. yum update CM 5.10.1
8. CDH 5.7.5 deactivate and CDH 5.9.1 activate

please advise to me

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't delete oldest parcel, you can active the CDH 5.10 from cloudera manager